# Unable to find valid certificate path to requested target

Tags: deployment, eclipse

I am trying yo deploy my application from developer org to newly purchased enterprise edition org.

For this I am using eclipse to deploy my developer org project to sandbox. But I'm not able to connect to sandbox. I get an error like:

> Unable to find valid certificate path to requested target

I tried to login through browser with the same credentials and it is working.
So as far as credentials are concerned it not an issue.

Comment: Re-install eclipse!

Comment: or download the certificate and add it into the eclipse keystore if reinstall does not work. Have you tried with MavensMate?

Comment: What zokito said. See if this helps - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110331/eclipse-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-targer/214429#214429

Answer (score 0):

First thing this issue is not from Salesforce side. Some tool/proxy server is blocking to download code to local system.