# Eclipse error: Unable to find valid certification path to requested targer

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I have installed force.com IDE successfully in eclipse and trying to create new project but i am getting the below error message. Coould you please help me to come out from this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit old but I just encountered the same problem and it turns out that on the corporate network there was a self signed root SSL certificate.

In order to overcome this problem I had to add the SSL into the JVM keystore as [described here](https://connect2id.com/blog/importing-ca-root-cert-into-jvm-trust-store)

Comment: great! this is working!  OP should accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Java truststore issue to me. If you had overwritten anything in the JVM installation, it may be affecting your connection to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue follow the below steps.

Go to Eclipse IDE  Windows → Preferences → Network Connections and set Active Provider to Direct.

This issue is related to the Eclipse IDE Network Connections, i found this workaround from below Link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576290/eclipse-neon-http-proxy-authentication-required-error/42691498#42691498