# Force.com IDE issue - unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: force.com, eclipse, force.com-ide

Getting below error while installing force.com project.

Eclipse : Marc
JDK 1.8
JRE 1.8 for 64 bit computer

[image: Unknown Error]

> Unable to fetch organization details for <s>redacted</s>
>
> unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>
> To ignore this error and create an empty Force.com Project without connecting to the server, click Create Offline.
>
> <kbd>Create Offline</kbd> <kbd>Abort</kbd> <kbd>Retry</kbd>

Comment: Are you in corporate proxy, if yes+ you'd need to do additional configurations.

Comment: You have also not included which version of eclipse are you using and Force.com version, maybe try installing different version of eclipse and Force.com plugin.

Comment: See if this helps - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110331/eclipse-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-targer/214429#214429