# Errpr: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

Tags: force.com, eclipse

I am unable to connect to salesforce through eclipse using force.com plugin Im getting an error: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. There is no issue with the version of JDK or force.com plugin as it works well when connected through WiFi, it doesnt work when connected to corporate network.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110331/eclipse-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-targer/205103?r=SearchResults#205103), you have to configure proxy. Why not switch to vscode, its lighter and faster.

Comment: That didnt resolve the issue.